# Printing with exactly 1 space if a single digit?

Tags: python, printing

I'm printing an integer, that may be 1 or 2 digits long. 
I'm using :

```
print str(myInt)
```

However, I want it to always print out something that is 2 'spaces' long. As in if myInt is only 1 digit, then I want it to be padded with a space then print out the digit. 
Is there a simple way to do that?
sample output of what I want:

```
 1
15
20
 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> print '{:2}'.format(1)
 1
>>> print '{:2}'.format(23)
23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x=[1,15,20,3]
print [re.sub(r"^0"," ",str(i).zfill(2)) for i  in x]
```

Output:`[' 1', '15', '20', ' 3']`

A tough way to do easy things :P

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output by doing:

```
print "%2s" % num
```

Where `2` is the minimum field width. For example:

```
print "%2s" % 4
print "%2s" % 12
```

will result in:

```
 4
12
```

If you need more leading spaces you just need to replace the `2` in `%2s` for the appropriate minimum field width. I recommend you read the [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you don't need to convert Intger to String.

```
val = 10
val1 = 1
print "%2d" % val
print "%2d" % val1
```

output:

```
10
 1
```