# I want the single digit numbers to line up better with the other multi digit numbers in my table

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

this is my code

```
def table():
    print(A)
    print(B)
    print(C)
    print(D)
```

this is what it looks like

```
[7, 13, 10, 8]
[12, 14, 6, 5]
[15, 9, 2, 11]
[1, 3, 0, 4]
```

I want the numbers to line up better, kinda like this.

```
[ 7, 13, 10,  8]
[12, 14,  6,  5]
[15,  9,  2, 11]
[ 1,  3,  0,  4]
```

or something better so that it's easier to read it. This would be especially necessary when the table gets bigger.

I found an old post that would solve my problem but I think it's for an older version of python so it doesn't work in the current version of python.

[Printing with exactly 1 space if a single digit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002179/printing-with-exactly-1-space-if-a-single-digit?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That old question/answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29002179/364696) works just fine with the current version of Python, you just need to add parens around the arguments to `print` (the old `print` was a statement, not a function, so no parentheses were needed).

For your specific case, code like:

```
print('[{}]'.format(','.join(map('{:3}'.format, A))))
```

would do the trick. That formats each element (using `map`) in `A` to (at least) three spaces wide via `'{:3}'.format` (you only asked for two, but you happened to leave a space after each comma, and we may as well use it if we encounter three digit values), padding with spaces, joins them together with commas via `','.join`, then puts the result in square brackets via `'[{}]'.format`.